# Como pegar o Result do Controller VRaptor com o Jquery?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, java-ee, vraptor

Eu tenho um controller.

NewsletterController.java

```
@Controller
public class NewsletterController{

       @Inject
       private Result result;

       @Post("/gravarEmail")
       public void gravarEmail(String email){

              String mensagemErro = "";
              CadastroEmail cadEmail = new CadastroEmail();
              cadEmail.setEmail(email);
              try{
                   cadEmail.gravar();
              }catch(Exception e){

                   e.printStackTrace();
                   mensagemErro = "Não foi possivel gravar o email";                  

              }

              result.include("mensagemErro",mensagemErro);

       }

}
```

E tenho o código

```js
$('#btnEnviar').click(function() {

  var email = $('email').val();

  $.post("/gravarEmail", {

    email: email

  }, function(status) {


    //Aqui é onde quero pegar o atributo do Controller o mensagemErro;


  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divEmail">

  Insira o email:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

</div>

<div id="divBtnGravar">

  <input type="button" name="Enviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar" />

</div>
```

O que eu pretendo é apenas pegar o conteúdo do `mensagemErro` setado no Controller e inserido no `result`. Lembrando que se vier 2 emails iguais estoura erro no banco e seta o `mensagemErro`

Como fazer isso?

Comment: tentou dar um console.log(status) pra ver o objeto que ele retorna?

Comment: @EmirMarques , o `console.log(status)` retorna 'success', acrescentei data no function ficando assim `function(data,status)` e o `data` retorna vazio, mas nada de eu conseguir pegar o `mensagemErro` que é preenchido no Controller

Comment: Tente o seguinte result.use(json()).from(mensagemErro).serialize();